# getting user list from the team project your in at TFS 2012 using C#

Tags: c#, tfs

My goal is to get the whole information of the users that are in the teamproject my user is in. Then I want to to get the email addresses of the users and send them the id of the task they have been assigned. (It's an exercise)

I succeed in connecting to the server with the following code:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsUri));
ITeamProjectCollectionService tpcService = tfs.GetService<ITeamProjectCollectionService>();
```

but I don't know how to continue from this point.

I searched for a solution but didn't find any good material.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve (all) users from the TFS Api by using the IIDentityManagementService.

```
IIdentityManagementService identityManagementService = tpcService.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
TeamFoundationIdentity[][] identities = 
    IdentityManagementService.ReadIdentities(
        IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,
        new[] { "Project Collection Valid Users" },
        MembershipQuery.Expanded,
        ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);
```

And then print out all E-Mails

```
foreach (var user in identities) {
    Console.WriteLine(user.GetAttribute("Mail", null));
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard! Can you explain me what "user" is? can you explain me how did you implement it?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope you get it now. User is a TeamFoundationIdentity.

Answer (score 2):

```
_identityManagementService = _collection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService2>();
var validUsers = _identityManagementService.ReadIdentities(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, new[] { "Project Collection Valid Users" }, MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None)[0][0].Members;
var users = _identityManagementService.ReadIdentities(validUsers, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None).Where(x => !x.IsContainer).ToArray();
```

`users` will hold simple objects, inspect the objects in debug to see available properties.
In the second `ReadIdentities` you can play with the `MembershipQuery` and `ReadIdentityOptions` parameters to get more information about the users.